# What are the possible values for Spark DataFrame hint function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What are the possible values can be used in the `hint` function of Spark `DataFrame`?

I was looking at the documentation, but not much helpful except `broadcast`
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an excellent source, from the master, himself:

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-hint-framework.html#specifying-query-hints

Comment: The link return 401, this is why you need to provide answers, not just links!

Comment: @thebluephantom - Just a few moments ago, the link was briefly giving me 401 for a bit, but now it's up. Not sure what happened there ...

Comment: May be paid now. I am unauthorized.

Comment: Maintenance it appears.

Comment: try this link https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-hint-framework.html